# getting the ClassCastException

Tags: java, exception, casting, classcastexception

I am getting the ClassCastException and can't find the reason why it occurs.

Here is where I have the problem: the line of (Semestre) casting:

```
private void F1(){
    int eol = listaSem.getCantNodos();

    Asignatura asig;
    for (int i = 0; i < eol; i++){
        Semestre seme = ((Semestre) listaSem.getData().getObjeto());
        ListaAsignatura listaAsig = (ListaAsignatura)seme.getDatos()[1];
        asig = (Asignatura) listaAsig.getData().getObjeto();
        System.out.println(asig.getSigla()+" | "+asig.getNombre()+" | Cantidad Justificaciones: "+asig.getCantJustificaciones());
    }
}
```

Here it is some more code that is important to the case:

```
public class Semestre implements ID, Datos{

private String sem;
private ListaAsignatura listaAsig;

public Semestre(String sem) {
    this.sem = sem;
    listaAsig = new ListaAsignatura();
}
@Override
public Object[] getDatos() {
    Object[] datos = new Object[2];
    datos[0] = sem;
    datos[1] = listaAsig;
```

---

```
public class Nodo {

private Object objeto;
private Nodo next;

public Nodo(Object objeto, Nodo next) {
    this.objeto = objeto;
    this.next = next;
}

public Object getObjeto(){
    return objeto;
}
```

---

```
public class Lista {

protected Nodo head;

public Lista() {
    head = new Nodo(null, null);
}

public Nodo getData() {
    if (head.getNext() != null) {
        Nodo lista = new Nodo(((Datos) head.getNext().getObjeto()).getDatos(), null);
        Nodo tail = lista;
        for (Nodo aux = head.getNext().getNext(); aux != null; aux = aux.getNext()) {
            tail.setNext(new Nodo(((Datos) aux.getObjeto()).getDatos(), null));
            tail = tail.getNext();
        }
        return lista;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should paste the relevant code (and classes) into the question instead of linking to a screenshot. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `Lista`, the method `getData()` returns a `Nodo` object that you create like this:

```java
Nodo lista = new Nodo(((Datos) head.getNext().getObjeto()).getDatos(), null);
```

This `Nodo` object will therefore have the field `objeto` set to the return value of method `getDatos()` from class `Semestre`, which is of type `Object[]`.

In the line that causes the problem in method `F1()`:

```java
Semestre seme = ((Semestre) listaSem.getData().getObjeto());
```

...you are taking this `Object[]` returned by `getObjeto()` and trying to cast it to `Semestre`, causing a `ClassCastException`.

To fix the problem, you can change that line and the one after it with the following two lines:

```java
Object[] datos = (Object[]) listaSem.getData().getObjeto();
ListaAsignatura listaAsig = (ListaAsignatura) datos[1];
```